# Applescript: print first or other specific pages

Tags: printing, applescript, osx-mavericks, sandbox

How can you instruct an application or the printer to only print the first page, a page range or just odd or even pages of a file? I attempt this with the help of the Preview app, which looks promising:

```
set theFile to "[file-path/file]""
tell application "Preview"
activate
print theFile with properties {target printer:"Printer", ending page:1} without «class pdlg»
--these properties isn't available for the printer app, here just limiting amount of printed pages
quit
end tell
```

But with this I'm bitten by the sandboxd process that tells me the file can't be opened for printing and I get a `deny file-read-data` result in the log.

In the CUPS suggestion by **adamh** I encounter issues with umlauts and have other execution issues as well, possibly also because of sandbox rules. The code works from the command line, but not when called in automated fashion.

I tried to look up useful examples of the print command in a reference, in my books and tried  searching the online Apple references, but I can't seem to find many examples fitting to the present day situation with sandbox, if any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could script printing by command line tool `lp` & `lpr`. 
These talk to CUPS, *Common Unix Printing System*

To target pages / ranges:

```
lp -o page-ranges=2-4 "my_great_document.pdf"
```

To call it from applescript use `do shell script`

e.g,

```
do shell script "lp -o page-ranges=2-4 'my_great_document.pdf'"
```

For more ideas see: http://www.cups.org/documentation.php/options.html

Comment: Thanks for this tip. However, this causes a big problem with files containing umlauts or other special characters in its name, which is a problem not associated with applescript. I used a quoted path to handle spaces. Perhaps if I could convert the file path to whatever Bash can handle.

Comment: Try wrapping your doc path in "" quotes, I just tried this and it worked: lp "hëllö.rtf"

Comment: Also if you can be more descriptive with what issues / errors the umlauts caused.

Comment: Yes, I used the variable $1 as I couldn't find a way to use the path variable set in Applescript inside the shell script, so inspired with your CUPS ideas i did a total shell script instead. At first it failed with references to permissions indicating sandboxing being involved, but quotes around it worked fine: `lp "$1"`. Edited your response, but please do it again you too as my voting is locked now even as I edited. (Maybe I just have to wait for a review)